# Error Binding strings with Angular 1.5 components

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-components

I am trying to bind a string through the html of an angular 1.5 component.  I am getting an error message that says:

```
Error: [$compile:nonassign] Expression ''My Title'' in attribute 'title' used with directive 'selectList' is non-assignable!
```

This is the html where I am calling the component:

index.html

```
<select-list title="'My Title'"></select-list>
```

and the component:

```
export var selectListComponent = {
    bindings: {
        title: "="
    },
    templateUrl: 'path/selectList.html',
    controller: selectListController
};
```

and the component html:

```
<div>{{$ctrl.title}}</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using two way binding and providing a constant string as the binding target.

You would need to change your component to use:

```
export var selectListComponent = {
    bindings: {
        title: "@"
    },
    templateUrl: 'path/selectList.html',
    controller: selectListController
};
```

The `@` will evaluate the value it is passed (a string in this case) and then perform one-way binding to the directive scope.

Comment: Thank you Simon, at first I was trying it with '<' for the one-way binding but I guess that is not for primitive data types?  marked as answer though, was exactly what was wrong